Conditional expectation given the rank of the variable
Suppose that we have a random variable $X$ with distribution $F_X(x)$. Define the rank of the variable as $R = F_X(X)$.
What can we say about $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R]$?

If $F_X(X)$ is strictly increasing then there is a one-to-one mapping between $R$ and $X$, and $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R] = F_X^{-1}(R)$.
I am interested in knowing if there is any relationship between this expectation and the quantile, such as an equality or inequality between then, particularly for cases where the CDF is not strictly increasing.


Does $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R] = X$ make sense notationally?  The expectation integrates out the $X$ on the left, but leaves it on the right.  $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R] = F^{-1}(R)$ looks more plausible to me when $F$ is bijective.

More generally, it is common to define the quantile function as the inverse of the CDF with $Q(r)=F^{-1}(r)$ as $\inf(x: F(x) \le r)$, suggesting $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R] =Q(R)$ though this only really makes sense in the support of $R$ which is ${F(x)}$ when $x$ is in the support of $X$.  This approach is not consistent with the commonly used calculation of the median if there is a range of values with $F(x)=\frac12$: this approach goes to the bottom of that range rather than the middle of the range.

I agree with the notation of your first comment and just edited it. How would you prove that it is equal to the quantile when $F$ is not strictly increasing or discontinuous?

To take a simple example, if $X$ is $0$ or $1$ each with probability $\frac12$, then $R$ is $\frac12$ or $1$ each with probability $\frac12$.  You get $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R=\frac12] =0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R=1] =1$ and this is it since the support of $R$ is ${\frac12,1}$.  This is consistent with my second comment, but $\mathbb{E}[X \mid R=\frac12] =0$ might be read as suggesting the median of $X$ is $0$, when it would be better to say $0$ is a median of $X$.

Got it, that's great intuition!

Always: $E[X|F_X(X)]=min[F_X^{-1}(F_X(X))]$

How would you go about proving this?

$X=min[F_X^{-1}(F_X(X))]$ almost surely.

In short, we can say that $E[X|F_X(X)]=X$, whether or not $F_X$ is bijective.
